# Event handling in Usercontrol in winform

Tags: winforms

I have a usercontrol to provide a data grid view and using it in a form. I have a decorator for this data grid view which provides the grouping functionality to this data grid view. Now all times a cell is clicked, the data grid view cell changed event is fired first and then the grouper event. Is there any way to change the event firing sequence?

Comment: Hmm, first time I've seen the words DataGridView and "decorator" used together in one sentence.  Are you talking about the Decorator pattern?  What is "the grouper event"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unregister the event from the datagridview, attach the decorator and then reregister the event.